# Is there a portable (Windows, Linux, MacOS, Android) way of opening memory mapped files?

Tags: c, linux, windows, memory-mapped-files

I have an application that writes relatively large files (compared to its input, not compared to the memory of the system) and spends roughly 80% of its time simply writing the output.  The application also supports a "-diff" option that tells it not to write the files, but instead compare what it would write to what is already there and generate an error message if there is a difference.

In the implementation of the -diff option.  I fopen the file and use fgetc to read it character by character to compare character by character to the stuff I would normally write.  Something like this pseudo-code (although the real code is much more complex, since I have various things where I want to ignore differences:

```
void my_fputs(new_text, file_to_diff_to) {
   for (c = *new_text; *c; ++c) {
      x = fgetc(file_to_diff_to);
      if (c != x) generated_error_message();
      }
}
```

My profiling indicates, that I spend most of my time in fgetc.  I presume dealing with buffering.  What I'd prefer is portable code that looked like this.

```
void my_fputs(new_text, file_to_diff_to) {
   for (c = *new_text; *c; ++c) {
      x = *file_to_diff_to;       
      if (c != x) generated_error_message();
      ++file_to_diff_to;
      }
}
```

Is there something relatively portable that would let me do that?  If it matters, I am reading the files in binary (not text mode).  I deal with cr/lf issues myself.

Comment: You tagged this as C++ but what you wrote looks a lot more like C

Comment: Not sure about Android but for the others there's always [boost.interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html#interprocess.sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.mapped_file).

Comment: `mmap` is portable.

Comment: There is no portable solution. But does it really matter? Just write your own wrapper around OS-specific APIs. Also `fgetc` has to lock/unlock the internal mutex so `fgetc_unlocked` can be used, but it is not available on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

`mmap` is quite portable and even works on Windows (I tried it with MinGW-w64) using the Windows port from: https://github.com/witwall/mman-win32/